# Can I carve up a suckling pig like you would an adult pig?

Tags: pork, butchering

I found this [video of a butcher carving up a half adult pig](http://vimeo.com/36558736) (not gory) really interesting and would like to learn how to do this on my own.  However, I could never eat a whole adult pig.

Would a suckling pig have all the same cuts of meat that an adult would? I'm wondering for example if you'd still be able to make bacon from the meat, or if there just wouldn't be enough fat there.

Comment: Most people I know would consider it waste of a baby pig. They are meant to be skewered and turned slowly over open flame, or at the least slow baked in a very big oven on a bed of vegetables. If they don't need to do that, they let the pig grow up before butchering it.

Comment: @rumtscho - I think the question is *why* though.  I suspect its too lean personally.  And the meat is probably already fairly tender, as opposed to an adult pig which needs the super long, whole day roasts to tenderize and the fat keeps it moist - but I don't have enough personal experience to say for sure.  You could probably use it, but would have to drastically change cooking methods.

Answer (score 4):

A suckling pig would have the same cuts as an adult, but they would obviously be much smaller and thus fiddlier to butcher.

Wikipedia reports that suckling pig meat is also quite gelatinous, so you might take all the time to butcher the thing and end up with meat you don't want to eat.

You could always start with *half* a pig, since they are obviously symmetrical, joint it up and then freeze and/or give away the various cuts. Cuts like the belly could be cured, and other cuts could be ground/minced or turned into sausage.

Comment: "end up with meat you don't want to eat"? Sounds like you are knocking gelatin. Don't do that. It is precisely the gelatin that makes suckling pig so juicy and delicious.

Comment: If you like gelatinous meat :)

Answer (score 0):

I feel the need to extend @ElendilTheTall's answer; where **HE** says

> "A suckling pig would have the same cuts as an adult"

This is true with one exception, the 'belly' is simply not suitable to be sliced for bacon (or even salt pork). There just isn't enough there to end up with anything worth calling bacon. However, the belly, such as it is, does make an excellent addition to any sausage you want to make. The fat will help with some of the cuts you might want to anchor a sausage with by adding both fat and flavor. Another factor to remember is that because it everything is proportionally undersized the pork loin is also too small to use for most common application; BUT it does make excellent Canadian Bacon, *if properly cured*.

Comment: Ahahahahaha where "she" says. Ahahaha! Just fyi, wrong gender. :)

Comment: Thank you Jay. Cos, I did mention that the cuts would be smaller, with the intended implication that some would be essentially unusable in the same way as cuts from an adult pig. :)

Comment: Is that the English translation of "fiddlier to butcher"? :) I just wanted to set a specific expectation for OP as I remember being a bit disappointed to have gotten no bacon out of a small pig... that is until I tasted the sausage and the Canadian bacon.

Comment: oh.. and I apologize for misplacing your gender, Mr. ElendilTheTall. I forget where I picked up the impression that you were a lady, but I shall not make that error again.

Comment: I forgive you - but not your ignorance of the lore of The Lord of the Rings, whence comes my nick ;)